# Is conditional mean independence, $E(e_i | x_i)=0$, a different assumption from $E(x e) = 0$? (from Hansen)

Tags: regression

This question comes out of Hansen's Econometrics ((https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf))

In section 2.18, we only impose the assumptions of finite variance and $Q_{xx}$ being positive definite, and then derive the linear projection coefficient $\beta = E(\textbf{x} \textbf{x}^\prime)^{-1} E(\textbf{x} y)$ as the minimizer of the expected squared error of the linear projection model $y = \textbf{x}^\prime {\beta} + e$. This leads to the implication (NOT the assumption) that $E(\textbf{x} e) = \textbf{0}$.

Then in section 4.4, under assumption 4.2, we have: $E(e_i | \textbf{x}_i)=0$.

My question is: is $E(e_i | \textbf{x}_i)=0$ a newly-imposed assumption in chapter 4? Or is it equivalent to the condition $E(\textbf{x} e) = \textbf{0}$ which we reached in chapter 2, not by assumption but by implication?

I know that $E(\textbf{x} e) = E(E(\textbf{x} e|\textbf{x})) = E(\textbf{x} E(e|\textbf{x}))$
 (by law of iterated expectations and conditioning theorem, respectively), so imposing the assumption that $E(e|\textbf{x}) = \textbf{0}$ yields the implication that $E(\textbf{x} e) = \textbf{0}$. But is the reverse true? Does $E(e_i | \textbf{x}_i)=0$ follow from $E(\textbf{x} e) = \textbf{0}$, or is $E(e_i | \textbf{x}_i)=0$ a new assumption that we're imposing?

Comment: maybe this is better placed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

$E(\mathbf{x}e)=0$ does not imply $E(e|\mathbf{x})=0$, to see that, suppose that x is a variable that always takes the value of zero, but $e$ is independent of $\mathbf x$ and has a mean of, say, $3$. Then the expected value of the product is necessarily $0$, but the conditional expectation will be equal to 3 (given independence, the conditional mean is equal to the unconditional mean).